# RABL with jquery Datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, rabl

In my rails app I am using RABL and on the front end I'm using jquery datatables to view lists of data (actually using angular with a datatable directive).

I'm trying to implement [server side pagination](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) which calls for a slightly different [return tree](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side)

There's a [good thread on a solution](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/405) to dealing with this within the RABL itself, but I'd rather have a function in my controller that wrapped the RABL result with the extra params.

For example in my controller I would rather have a

```
respond_with_datatable(@books)
```

whereas this method somehow calls the respond_with(@books) method and just returns the json array of foo's and within this method I can set up the appropriate response:

```
{
"sEcho": 1,
"iTotalRecords": 53,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
"aaData": [book_array]
}
```

I don't believe there is a method I can call which simply does what respond_with(object) does and just captures the json without responding.  The benefit of using a method in the controller is that I don't need to change the RABL and I have some cases where I want to return the extra datatables format and other cases where I don't.  Having the control in the controller is ideal. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `render_to_string` to render your RABL template into a string, and then deal with it from there.  For instance you could parse it back to JSON and then manipulate it or embed it in a bigger JSON structure.  Then you can use `render` to respond directly with your new data.

I just tested this in my app

```
def index
  @galleries = Gallery.all # or whatever
  respond_with_datatable
end

def respond_with_datatable
  template_json = JSON(render_to_string)
  json = {:new_data => "some new stuff", :orig_data => template_json}
  render :json => json
end
```